# Stop a list in Python being shared between function invocations when multiprocessing

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

I'm passing a function into a queue for parallel processing via `multiprocessing`, and that function takes 2 lists as inputs.  I'm doing this in a loop 6 times, where each time I append the loops counter to the end of the list (see output section below).  I would have expected each list to be a unique local variable for each function execution, but it seems like they're sharing memory pointers, and each time the function runs the list just gets longer.  How can I make each list be a distinct variable?  I've found many questions on here about trying to *make* a shared varaible, but none about *unsharing* one

Or alternatively, is there a better/different way I should be doing this in the first place?  I'm largely copy/pasting code snippits for the multiprocessing part, as I'm A) Not great at scripting in general; and B) never tried parallel processing before

Background:
I'm trying to test every possible die combination using the rules of Risk and output the probability of the attacker or defender winning, but instead of the normal "Attacker rolls 3 die, defender rolls 2", I'm looking at larger numbers of die for both, and am trying to add parallel processing to the script to combat the exponential increase in time per extra die.

Code snippit (simplified for testing)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
#good break down of logic for traditional 3v2 in here: http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/november22011/index.html
#multithreading logic from: https://superfastpython.com/parallel-nested-for-loops-in-python/

import threading
import multiprocessing.pool
import queue

def compare(attack, defence):
    aWon = 0
    print(defence)
    for i in range(len(defence)):
        if attack[i] > defence[i]:
            aWon += 1
    aWins[aWon] += 1 #aWins is a shared global array to keep track of how many attacker die won a given encounter
 
def d1(attack, defence):
    global queue
    defence.sort(reverse=True)
    for i in range(1, 7):
        defence.append(i+10)
        queue.put((compare(attack, defence), (i,)))

aWins = [0,0,0,0,0,0] #0 index incremented when attacker won 0 die in a set; 1 index when they won 1, etc
global queue
queue = queue.Queue()
queue.put((d1([1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,1])))
 
total_tasks = 216
with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(total_tasks) as pool:
    for _ in range(total_tasks):
        task, args = queue.get()
        pool.apply_async(task, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

debug/print output:

```
[1, 1, 11]
[1, 1, 11, 12]
[1, 1, 11, 12, 13]
[1, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[1, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Expected debug/print output

```
[1, 1, 11]
[1, 1, 12]
[1, 1, 13]
[1, 1, 14]
[1, 1, 15]
```

Comment: Did you intend to use `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`?  You're using multithreading rather than multiprocessing.  Variables are not copied in the former.

Comment: Intent to?  Nope, no clue what I'm doing :D
I just tried changing it though, and its the same result

Comment: You're not putting the functions into the queue, you're running the functions directly before putting their results into the queue. You should do `queue.put((d1, ([1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,1])))` (so `d1` is the first element of the tuple and the arguments are the second).